# Rails app with multiple user types and how to model database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have started developing apps for Rails for last couple of months but there is always one question bugging me. How should I model my database if I have multiple user types and each of them has their own columns?

Before I had it simple like this:

```
create_table "users", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "username"
  t.string   "password"
  t.boolean  "admin",           default: false
  t.boolean  "editor",          default: false
  t.boolean  "publisher",       default: false
  t.boolean  "designer",        default: false
end
```

When I needed something specific to certain user type in my View or Controller, I just checked is the certain column in 'users' table 'true' or 'false'. That was enough as user types didn't have anything which would be specific to them. Now I have to add many new columns which are only meant for certain user types. If I add those columns I will have many 'null' values inside my 'users' table. For example:

```
create_table "users", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "username"
  t.string   "password"
  t.boolean  "admin_column1"
  t.boolean  "admin_column2"
  t.boolean  "editor_column1"
  t.boolean  "editor_column2"
  t.boolean  "publisher_column1"
  t.boolean  "publisher_column2"
  t.boolean  "designer_column1"
  t.boolean  "designer_column2"
  t.boolean  "admin",           default: false
  t.boolean  "editor",          default: false
  t.boolean  "publisher",       default: false
  t.boolean  "designer",        default: false
end
```

This means that if I create a user who is 'editor', I will have something like this inside my table:

```
  "username": editorUsername
  "password": editorPassword
  "admin_column1": null
  "admin_column2": null
  "editor_column1": editorData1
  "editor_column2": editorData2
  "publisher_column1": null
  "publisher_column2": null
  "designer_column1": null
  "designer_column2": null
  "admin": false
  "editor": true
  "publisher": false
  "designer": false
```

So, as you can see I will have a lot of 'null' values in each row. What would be the recommended way to deal with this situation?

Comment: Have you considered using roles for user instead?

Comment: You can use [`STI`](http://eewang.github.io/blog/2013/03/12/how-and-when-to-use-single-table-inheritance-in-rails/)

Comment: @Mandeep, thanks but wouldn't that produce the same problem again with many null values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd encourage you to have roles for user instead. Create a new model:

```
rails g model role name:string
```

and a migration for intermediate table:

```
rails g migration CreateRolesUsers user_id:integer role_id:integer
```

Run: `$ rake db:migrate`

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
end
```

Alright, let's create new roles:

```
Role.create(name: 'admin')
Role.create(name: 'editor')
Role.create(name: 'publisher')
Role.create(name: 'designer')
Role.create(name: 'guest')
```

New roles are good to be assigned to users, for example:

```
User.find(1).roles << Role.find_by(name: 'admin')
```

Now, you're all set to use [cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) gem for authorization of your users as per their roles, which you've just created and assigned. Here's an awesome [RailsCasts by Ryan Bates on cancan](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan) for better understanding of the previous gem to get it working.

Comment: Thank you, +1. What can I do if I want to avoid using cancan? Would be bad if I create three tables for 3 types of users?

Comment: @Bosquets : So, in future, if you have to add a new type, you'll have to create a new table and then add code to make it work accordingly. Won't it much simpler and feasible to just add a new role entry and change Ability file and your app is up and running in minutes? Sure, you can avoid cancan, my intention was to give you an impression that you'd need an authorization library to solve this problem. Of course you can write your own code with `if-else` and helper methods, but that'll get complex and will add maintenance overhead(speaking from experience, have done it before).

Comment: This is so far the best approach to tackle such situations I know, for now. Another way to do is with STI, but then one table will become a dumping ground of all unnecessary data sooner than later(again, I have had tried it before) as your application grows.

Comment: To achieve exactly the same thing you can use Rolify gem. It's even simpler to setup and aditionally you receive some cool features like roles scoped to particular model class or instance.